# How can I split my string and delete the first item for every row in my dataframe? key error 18

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELIau.png)

I keep getting key error 18 and dont know how to solve it. I am trying to split the values of a column and delete the first element of the list.

This is my code:

```
 last_name= []

for i in train.index:

#Split at space and delete the first name  

   name_id = test_df_bin['Name'][i].split(' ')
   del name_id[0]

 #list of last name
   last_name.append(name_id[0])


test_df_bin['Surname'] = last_name`
```

*Error messege:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3622 except KeyError as err:

KeyError: 18*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest against looping unless strictly necessary. In this case you can achieve your desired solution with:

```
test_df_bin['Surname'] = test_df_bin['Name'].str.split().str[1:]
```

If you'd like the output of the `split()` joined back into a single string, then:

```
test_df_bin['Surname'] = [' '.join(x) for x in test_df_bin['Name'].str.split().str[1:]]
```

Comment: Happy to be of help! Feel free to accept the answer using the tick symbol to mark this question as solved.

Comment: How do I change the column from containing a list to a str?

Comment: Use the second approach